# Meta Question (feature request) : poll instead of furious downvoting?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, down-votes, polling

When people ask for a feature request on meta, people either like it, or furiously vote it down. Couldn't we have a poll instead or simply answers like "I agree" or "I disagree".

*I'll tag this as discussion and feature request because it's both at the same time. And don't downvote just to make the joke.*

Comment: For some reason I felt compelled to downvote to just to make the joke.

Comment: Downvoting to make a joke is even worse.

Comment: For some reason, I really love the sound of the term "furious downvoting".

Comment: @Silence: don't take downvotes and opinions in Meta too personal. The voting system works as a poll on poll questions.

Comment: If you are that worried about it, post your request as CW. No rep gained or lost. Problem solved.

Comment: If you are truly worried about your rep on *Meta*, then don't post lousy suggestions. Simple as that. I've been constantly surprised, both on Meta and on UserVoice before it, how often people show up proposing major changes to how SO works, and fail to include any sort of justification for the change... and then when their idea is shot down, whine about it. Rule of thumb: if right off the bat folks are putting more detail into criticizing your suggestion than you put into justifying it, **you've failed**.

Comment: Shog9 : flagged as offensive.

Comment: @Troggy: It reminds me of the bible passage Samuel L. Jackson recites from Pulp Fiction: "And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger..."

Comment: I love it, now someone downvoted my "Why are people afraid of downvotes?" question.  haha. @Silence: Did you notice you have gained more rep then lost from this question, even after all the downvotes?

Comment: It's not about the rep Troggy. Imagine you study real hard for an exam, pass it, confident, hoping for the best. Then comes your grade : 8 %. Some are gonna say : "forget it, grades aren't important ! Just study harder at the final."  But it's not about the grades. It's about the expectation of doing something good. I thought I had ideas that would improve the whole site. So I proposed one. The higher the expectations, the harder you fall when people just say "you are failure" in form of a downvote (sometimes without even a comment). Makes me wanna stop helping others. Screw them. Screw you.

Comment: @Silence : flagged as offensive.

Comment: What ? That's not offensive.

Comment: @Silence: offensive is subjective. And if you feel like a failure because someone disagrees with your proposal, then you need to ask yourself what you're actually looking for when you propose a change.

Comment: "don't post lousy suggestions", "you've failed" are offensive.

Comment: @Silence: Woah man, do you really take these websites that personal? It is just a question/answer website. This isn't a savetheworld or happyself website. Downvotes are just people disagreeing with your request a lot of the time on meta. Why is that bad? Everyone comes up with unpopular ideas sometimes. A feature request is not a life goal that you have failed. I have never seen a more personal comparison/analogy of a downvote.

Comment: Oh, and the rep thing was simply a comment, FYI, note, etc. That's all.

Comment: I'm developper. All I have is my ideas. If my ideas aren't good, then I have nothing else. What about you ?

Comment: @Silence: so apparently, you can't handle down-votes, and you can't handle criticism. You expect to post a half-baked suggestion and be lauded for it, despite your lack of research and unwillingness to put in any real effort. Sorry brother, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Voting to close as noise, since *we don't encourage poll questions at all*.

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want a downvoted feature request to hurt your rep, why not make it a wiki?  After all, the nature of the question begs for the users to just upvote or downvote the actual question.  And, as previously mentioned, it actually makes meta for features useful - the questions naturally sort based on interest.

Comment: But, no wiki abuse.

Comment: Could you tell me where is that wiki?

Answer (score 9):

**No.**

This has been said how meta works. Down votes here mean either bad/not good question or they simply disagree with the request. I think the system is working well here as is. Remember to not take voting and reputation on meta personal even more so then the other sites. Voting is the community response to feature requests and Jeff and his crew use that information during site modifications/additions.

Comment: Can't they use the poll information instead ?

Comment: Not everything is a poll on meta. The voting system also evaluates bugs and other issues that may be popular/important or not.

Comment: Voting is almost like a poll in a sense. If more people don't like it, it will be negative and vise versa.

Comment: I good example of this is the moderator voting. I think you will be kind enough to find use the link :)

Comment: So the down vote has two different meanings.  It is not fair.

Answer (score 7):

I see nothing wrong with the current system.

The voting system does exactly what it should.

Jeff even mentioned that he will browse the feature-request tag and look at highly voted feature requests.

If the requests themselves don't get voted on, they won't be sorted by most liked requests.  It completely breaks the idea of using meta in replacement of uservoice.

Also, mixing poll answers in with discussion answers seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Can't they use the poll information instead ?

Comment: It isn't nearly as easy or intuitive to do.

Comment: Also, mixing poll answers in with discussion answers seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Think of meta votes an *idea popularity contest*. Mostly. Sometimes there's just votes for lulz.